# multiple graphs for kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using multiple series for scatter graph in kendo(each series represent one attribute). Since every series has multiple ranges, hence I am required to NOT use multiple series instead draw each graph separately and show in the same window. Is there any option provided for the same?

Ex:

Please see the below URL:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scatter-charts/scatter-line

I have the same requirement as above, except the 3 graphs '0.8C', 1.8C' and '3.1C' have to be drawn as separate graphs(separate X and Y axis) but should be displayed in the same window? Is it possible? Any response will be highly appreciated.

Edit: I found one image(via google) to represent what I intend to say:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at using panes: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UMEQa, docs: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-panes

Comment: Superb! Thanks a ton!!